# Using ANTLR4 in .NET Core without the use of external Java library?

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, antlr, antlr4

I've followed through [these](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs) instructions but I get a ton of compilation errors after the files have been compiled.

What I have done:

1. Created a new Console project in .NET Core 3.1.
2. Installed NuGet package Antlr4.
3. Added a new text file named `example.g4` to the project, and saved it in encoding UTF-8 without signature.
4. Populated the grammar with some demo features.
5. Build Solution.
6. Ton of errors after successful compilation of lexer/visitor/parser/etc.

Some of those errors include the following:

`The name '_interp' does not exist in the current context   AntlrDemo   C:\AntlrDemo\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\exampleLexer.cs    45  Active`

`'ParserATNSimulator' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments AntlrDemo   C:\AntlrDemo\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\exampleParser.cs   95  Active`

`'exampleParser.TokenNames': no suitable method found to override   AntlrDemo   C:\AntlrDemo\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\exampleParser.cs   69  Active`

What's going on?

The issue is not from the grammar - it successfully compiles in .NET Framework.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind working with the official Antlr4 code generator and runtime, but don't want to actually download and install Java and the Antlr Tool .jar by hand, try this instead:

- Install the latest NET 5, or use old NET Core.
- dotnet new -i Antlr4BuildTasks.Templates
- mkdir Foo
- cd Foo
- dotnet new antlr
- dotnet build
- dotnet run

This does use the Antlr4 Java tool, but it's completely hidden. You don't download the runtime, nor Java. It's all contained in the Antlr4BuildTasks tool that you just reference in your .csproj. If you want to work with an older Antlr4 version, like 4.8 or 4.7, Antlr4BuildTasks will download the tool and runtime from Maven Central and NuGet.org; you just set the versions in the .csproj file then "dotnet build".

I have another tool that generates a driver for grammar and support code for C# (both official and Harwell's version), Java, and JavaScript targets. It is now being used for CI in github.com/antlr/grammars-v4.

If you try swapping between Antlr4 (the official Antlr4) and Antlr4cs (Harwell's tool/runtime), you will find the tools and runtime are quite different. There is no shim to allow code written for one runtime to be used in the other, but I am working on one.

As far as the `<PrivateAssets>` code in the .csproj file, getting rid of the lines as you suggest is fine. The reason it is included is to not propagate the dependent assemblies of the build tool directly into your code. But, while the tool is only useful in building the app, not running it, `<PrivateAssets>` doesn't prevent the assembly for the tool itself is still being included.

--Ken

Comment: Why did I have to remove `<IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>` from Antlr4 nuGet package in order to get it running? This is so confusing. What antlr4 version is the `Antlr4` nuGet package using? The nuget version itself is 4.6.6. (Latest one for net core 3.1)

Comment: It's difficult to say why this worked with `IncludeAssets` removed. You don't give your code, and there is no "example.g4" under github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs (Harwell's code). Further, Recognizer._interp is a protected internal field in the class, so it should not be available, as per error message. There is a Get property wrapper for _interp. Make sure not to mix PackageReference of Antlr4.Runtime.Standard/Antlr4BuildTasks with Harwell's Antlr4/Antlr4.Runtime in your .csproj. Harwell's code is several years behind the official Antlr4 code (github.com/antlr/antlr4).

Answer (score 2):

After you install `Antlr4` NuGet package, the following code is added to your .csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Antlr4" Version="4.6.6">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

The fix was to change the above to the following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Antlr4" Version="4.6.6">
      <!--<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>-->
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

It also seems to work by uncommenting the `PrivateAssets` element. But I have no idea what the actual problem is here, and if I'm doing something wrong. Can someone shine some light about it?

EDIT: Another alternative solution is to instead install the two NuGet Packages `Antlr4.CodeGenerator` and `Antlr4.Runtime`.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, this won't cause more confusion. I just moved my C# parser library from NET Framework 4.8 to NET 5 and was able to build it without errors with this .csproj file.

I changed the target framework from net5.0 to net5.0-windows7.0 in the example below to avoid compiler warning CA1416 which protested that I was using debug print methods (based on Console.Writeline calls with param[] arguments) in my code. I wanted to keep my debugging messages so I switched from the net5.0 target.

But the plain 'net5.0' compiled okay for me (except for the warnings I just described). My simple test cases ran fine with net5.0.

Here is an excerpt from my class library file, showing that I could leave the `PrivateAssets` and `IncludeAssets` lines alone.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- use net5.0-windows7.0 to avoid CA1416 warnings about Console Writeline calls only available in win7 and later-->
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Antlr4" Version="4.6.6">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Antlr4.Runtime" Version="4.6.6" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Here is an excerpt from my unit test project, showing the inclusion of Antlr4(4.6.6) and the Antlr4.Runtime(4.6.6).

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Antlr4" Version="4.6.6">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Antlr4.Runtime" Version="4.6.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.0">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```